# Solving $2x^3-5ix^2+3x+4i=0$, need $(21x_1-1)^{-2}+(21x_2-1)^{-2}+(21x_3-1)^{-2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have this polynomial from **Problemas selectos (Lumbreras editors)**:

$$2x^3-5ix^2+3x+4i=0$$

I make $x=it$. then:

$$2(it)^3-5i(it)^2+3it+4i=0$$

$$i(-2it^3+5it^2+3it+4)=0$$

$$2t^3-5t^2-3t-4=0$$

$$8t^3-20t^2-12t-16=0$$

$$(2t)^3-3(2t)^2(5/3)+(50/3)t-125/27-(14/3)t-307/27=0$$

$$(2t-5/3)^3-(86/3)t-307/27=0$$

If $2t-5/3=z$, then:

$$z^3-(43/3)z-952/27=0$$

Where $p=-\frac{43}{3}$ and $q=-\frac{952}{27}$

When $A=-\frac{q}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4}+\frac{p^3}{27}}$ and $B=-\frac{q}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4}+\frac{p^3}{27}}$

We have $z_1=\sqrt[3]{A}+\sqrt[3]{B}$, $z_2=-\frac{\sqrt[3]{A}+\sqrt[3]{B}}{2}+i\sqrt{3}\frac{\sqrt[3]{A}-\sqrt[3]{B}}{2}$, $z_3=-\frac{\sqrt[3]{A}+\sqrt[3]{B}}{2}-i\sqrt{3}\frac{\sqrt[3]{A}-\sqrt[3]{B}}{2}$

There for $x_n=\frac{i}{2}(z_n+\frac{5}{3})$,

Comment: Hint: the coefficients are real for odd powers of $x$, and purely imaginary for even powers, which can suggest a shortcut. Or else write $x=a+ib$ and expand.

Comment: You can check for pure imaginary roots by taking $x = it$  and expanding. After dividing out a common factor of $i$ the result is a real coefficient polynomial in $t$ set to zero. There is at least one real $t$ that works

Comment: This equation doesn't even have one nice solution, what's the point of the question? We need more context.

Comment: The point is to find the most ingenious solution, SilentMath

Comment: Good idea! @WillJagy

Comment: If it was a $+5ix^2$ then $i$ would be a zero. Making things much nicer.

Comment: It would be a tiresome job, but one may use the $\Bbb Q(i)$-analog of the Rational Root Theorem. Seems to me that there are $28$ possible elements of $\Bbb Q(i)$ that are candidates according to the Theorem. Not anything I’d care to try by hand, but a symbolic package would make short shrift of the task.

Comment: waning: the solution of the first polynomial is different from the two of bottom. they are no the same. the partition in two is just a subset of the entery family solution.

Comment: It does not follow that $(2x^3 + 3x) = Re(2x^3-5ix^2+3x+4i)$ or that $4-5x^2 = Im(2x^3-5ix^2+3x+4i)$ so your conclusion they are both $0$ is not valid.  However $2x^3 + 3x = -(4-5x^2) i$ which means if $4-5x^2 = a+bi$ then $2x^3 + 3x=b-ai$.

Comment: Note: $z + yi =  3+4i$ will have $z = 5+6i$ and $y = -2 +2i$ as one set of infinitely many solutions.  So $z+y i = 0$ does *NOT* imply $z =3$ and $y=4$.

Comment: @fleablood I guess that $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is assumed in that step, resulting in the subsequent observation that "$x$ does not belong to the real numbers".

Comment: Yes but once you know $x$ can not be real (which the OP did correctly) then you can *not* assume $(2x^3 + 3x) = 0$ or that $4-5x^2 = 0$.  And as will jagy cleverly suggested if you assume $x=it$ is purely *imaginary* you get $2x^3 + 3x = i(-2t^3 + 3t)$ and $(4-5x^2)i = (4+5t^2)i$ so you $0 + (-2t^3+3t +4-5t^2)i = 0$; an equation with *only* imaginary component.  A different equation altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you need $ \ (21x_1-1)^2+(21x_2-1)^2+(21x_3-1)^2=S \ $ (Let's say)

Now $S = (21x_1-1)^2+(21x_2-1)^2+(21x_3-1)^2 \\ 
 \implies S = 21^2(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2) -42(x_1+x_2+x_3) + 3 \\ 
 \implies S = 21^2(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2 -2(21^2)(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1)-42(x_1+x_2+x_3)+3 \\
\left[{\because x_1,x_2,x_3 \ \text{are roots of the given equation} \ 2x^3 - 5ix^2+3x+4i=0 \\ x_1+x_2+x_3 =\frac{5i}{2} , x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1 =\frac{3}{2} }\right] \\ 
 \implies S = 21^2(\frac{5i}{2})^2-2(21^2)(\frac{3}{2})-42(\frac{5i}{2})+3 \\ 
\implies S =-\frac{11025}{4}-1323-105i+3 \\
\implies S = -4076.25 - 105i \\ 
\boxed {\therefore (21x_1-1)^2+(21x_2-1)^2+(21x_3-1)^2 = -4076.25 - 105i } $

Done.

As you already knew the roots (from other answers) this is a way without finding them.

The question was changed so we need $\ (21x_1-1)^{-2}+(21x_2-1)^{-2}+(21x_3-1)^{-2}=K \ $

To get this we use the following substitution $z=(21x -1)$

We get  $ x = \frac {z + 1}{21} $

Now put this in the original equation

$2\left(\frac{z+1}{21}\right)^3 -5i\left(\frac{z+1}{21}\right)^2+3\left(\frac{z+1}{21}\right)+4i=0 \ \to (1) $

Now

$z_1 = 21x_1-1 \\
z_2 = 21x_2-1 \\
z_2 = 21x_2-1 \\ $

So we need $K= \frac{1}{z_1^2}+\frac{1}{z_2^2}+\frac{1}{z_3^2}$

$\implies K = \frac{z_1^2z_2^2+z_2^2z_3^2+z_3^2z_1^2}{z_1^2z_2^2z_3^2} \\ 
\implies K = \frac{(z_1z_2+z_2z_3+z_3z_1)^2-2z_1z_2z_3(z_1+z_2+z_3)}{z_1^2z_2^2z_3^2}$

From equation $(1)$ We can get $z_1+z_2+z_3,z_1z_2+z_2z_3+z_3z_1,z_1z_2z_3$

So we can find $K$

Comment: Why 21?${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Friend G. Sai Rithvick, I need,$(21x_1−1)^{-2}+(21x2−1)^{-2}+(21x3−1)^{-2}$

Comment: @ArnoldFernández It is very inconsiderate to change the question after each answer, so please don't. If you have a new, different question then ask a new, different question.

Comment: @ArnoldFernández I have edited answer please check that

Answer (score 2):

Starting from @mjw's answer, you face a cubic equation with only one real root in $y$  since $\Delta=-5447$.

Using the hyperbolic method for this root, we then have

$$y_1=\frac{5}{6}+\frac{\sqrt{43}}{3}  \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{476}{43 \sqrt{43}}\right)\right)=3.17174\cdots$$
Now, deflate the cubic and get the quadratic equation
$y^2+Ay+B=0$ where
$$A=y_1-\frac{5}{2}\qquad \text{and} \qquad B=\frac 2 {y_1}$$

Numerically, they are $y_{2,3}=-0.335868\pm 0.719557\, i$  as already given by @mjw.

Comment: Also a nice formula!  Lots of 43's!

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x$ is pure imaginary.

$x=iy$, with $y$ real.

We have:

$$- 2i y^3 +5 i y^2 +3iy +4 i =0$$
or

$$2 y^3 -5  y^2 -3y -4  =0$$

This leads to the solution

$$y \approx 3.17174.$$

The other solutions are

$$y \approx -0.335868 \mp 0.719557 i$$

and the solutions to the original problem are $x=iy.$

There are techniques to solve cubic equations exactly.  I admit that I am not so familiar with them (we could look them up!), so you've got here a numerical solution.

Comment: Nice formula for the real root in $y$, isn't it ? Cheers :-)